# Atributo de uma struct receber várias structs

Tags: c++, dll

É possível um atributo de uma `struct` receber várias structs?

Por exemplo, preciso que o atributo `LPWFSPINFDK lppFDKs;` que faz parte da struct `_wfs_pin_func_key_detail`, receba várias structs `_wfs_pin_fdk`.

Estou tentando dessa maneira, compila, porém o programa final não reconhece:

```
    WFSPINFUNCKEYDETAIL PinFunKeyDetail;

    WFSPINFDK ObjPinKey;
    LPWFSPINFDK PinKey;
    PinKey = &ObjPinKey;

    PinKey->ulFDK = WFS_PIN_FK_FDK01;
    PinKey->usXPosition = 5;
    PinKey->usYPosition = 5;

    PinFunKeyDetail.lppFDKs = &PinKey;
```

STRUCT: **_wfs_pin_fdk**

```
typedef struct _wfs_pin_fdk
{
    ULONG               ulFDK;
    USHORT              usXPosition;
    USHORT              usYPosition;
} WFSPINFDK, * LPWFSPINFDK;
```

STRUCT: **_wfs_pin_func_key_detail**

```
typedef struct _wfs_pin_func_key_detail
{
    ULONG               ulFuncMask;
    USHORT              usNumberFDKs;
    LPWFSPINFDK       * lppFDKs; //Aqui recebo as structs
} WFSPINFUNCKEYDETAIL, * LPWFSPINFUNCKEYDETAIL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo: É possível um atributo de uma `struct` receber várias `structs`. O atributo a que você se refere, porém, é apenas um ponteiro, e não um contêiner. Ponteiros não podem *receber várias structs*, apenas endereços destas.

Algo que pode *receber várias structs* seria um `std::vector<_wfs_pin_fdk>`.

---

Pelos trechos postados, `LPWFSPINFDK` é um tipo definido como ponteiro para `_wfs_pin_fdk`.

Na classe `_wfs_pin_func_key_detail`, o atributo `lppFDKs` é um ponteiro para `LPWFSPINFDK`.

Ou seja: `lppFDKs` é um ponteiro para ponteiro de `_wfs_pin_fdk`.

Talvez você esqueceu de definir `usNumberFDKs` ? Inferindo pelo nome da variável, ela parece guardar quantos ponteiros para `_wfs_pin_fdk` são guardados em `lppFDKs`.

Alterando seu exemplo para que `lppFDKs` aponte para uma array de vários ponteiros:

```
WFSPINFUNCKEYDETAIL PinFunKeyDetail;

//três _wfs_pin_fdk
WFSPINFDK PinKeyA;
WFSPINFDK PinKeyB;
WFSPINFDK PinKeyC;

//(..algum código manipulado os _wfs_pin_fdk..)

//endereço dos três _wfs_pin_fdk , em array
LPWFSPINFDK PinKeys[3] = {
    &PinKeyA,
    &PinKeyB,
    &PinKeyC
};

//passa para lppFDKs o endereço da array de LPWFSPINFDK
PinFunKeyDetail.lppFDKs = PinKeys;

//palpite: esse atributo indica quandos elementos são apontados por lppFDKs 
PinFunKeyDetail.usNumberFDKs = 3;
```

Você disse que

> o programa final não reconhece

Mas isso é muito vago, não sei a que programa está referindo-se. [Aqui está o código online](http://ideone.com/1vusWB), compilando no *Ideone*.